# Comparison with undefined or "undefined" when checking for object property. What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

I encountered this difference between `undefined` and `"undefined"` and I am trying to understand it.

I was checking whether properties in objects are defined or not. 
In first example I checked whether property is not undefined. All the test below evaluates to true. It doesn't matter whether I use `"undefined"` or `undefined`.

```js
var test = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
};

if (test.x != "undefined") console.log('test.x != "undefined"'); //TRUE
if (test.x !== "undefined") console.log('test.x !== "undefined"'); //TRUE
if (test.x != undefined) console.log('test.x != undefined'); //TRUE
if (test.x !== undefined) console.log('test.x !== undefined'); //TRUE
```

Then I tried it with property which is not defined.It only evaluates to true if i use `undefined` (not string literal) or with `typeof`.

```js
var test = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
};

if (test.z === undefined) console.log("test.z === undefined"); //TRUE
if (test.z == undefined) console.log("test.z == undefined"); //TRUE
if (test.z === "undefined") console.log("test.z === 'undefined'"); //FALSE
if (test.z == "undefined") console.log("test.z == 'undefined'"); //FALSE
if (typeof test.z === "undefined") console.log("typeof test.z === 'undefined'"); //TRUE
```

So my question is: why the difference (I guess I don't understand something ...). Is it bad practice that I used comparison to "undefined"/undefined rather than `.hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to check. Most of the times, you can simply use something like this: `if(test.x){...}` or `if(!text.z){...}`. These kinds of conditions check of a lot of things like `undefined`, *empty string*, `0`, `null`, `false`.

Comment: @Titus: I wan't to check only if it exist; next stage is switch() depending on what the property is.

Comment: In that case, you can write the `switch` statement directly, there is no need for a check first.

Comment: @Titus: I tested that and you are right. I was afraid it would throw an error but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined` and `"undefined"` are different values. The former is `undefined`, the latter is a string.

What you've probably seen isn't `x === "undefined"` and `x === undefined`, but rather `typeof x === "undefined"` and `x === undefined`. Note the `typeof`. One of the reasons you see the former (with `typeof`) is historic and no longer relevant, but not all of the reasons are.

Assuming a declared identifier `x` and that `undefined` has not been *shadowed*, these two statements are effectively the same other than the first one has to do a teensy bit more work:

```
typeof x === "undefined"
x === undefined
```

But if `x` **isn't** declared, the former will evaluate true, and the latter will fail with a ReferenceError. (In the general case, you probably *want* the ReferenceError as it alerts you to the undeclared idenfier, but there are use cases for the former.)

But `undefined` is, unfortunately, not a keyword (like `null`); it's a *global constant*. That means that `undefined` can be *shadowed*:

```js
function foo(undefined) {
  var x; // x defaults to the value undefined
  console.log(typeof x === "undefined"); // true
  console.log(x === undefined);          // false?!?!
}
foo(42);
```

In practice, if you find someone shadowing `undefined` and giving it a value other than `undefined`, take them out back and beat them about the head and shoulders with a wet noodle until they see sense. But...

Historically, there was many years ago a problem with the `undefined` value in one window not being `===` to the `undefined` value. And so if you had code that might be dealing with values from across windows, comparing with `=== undefined` wasn't a reliable way to check for `undefined`. A couple of years back I checked all even vaguely-recent browsers and that wasn't an issue (I suspect it hasn't been for much longer than that).

Answer (score 1):

When you are checking for `"undefined"` (in quotes) then you are checking for string with value `"undefined"`.

Whereas when you are checking for `undefined` then it is checked if the property or the variable is defined or not. Therefore you can use this to check if the property is defined.